# kubernetes lost ~/.kube/config

Tags: kubernetes, devops

Unfortunately I lost my local

> ~/.kube/config

where I had configuration for my namespace.

Is there a way to get this config if I have access to master nodes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which platform you're using for creating kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you're using kubeadm to start your kubernetes cluster, you can generate the new kubeconfig file using following command:

```
kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig admin --kubeconfig-dir /etc/kubernetes --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/pki
```

This will generate a new config file in `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`. Then you can copy the file in following way:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Comment: Thanks! It's now `kubeadm init` (instead of kubeadm alpha)

Answer (score 1):

No need to re-install kubernetes. Just copy the file from `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`.

```sh
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PrafullLadha, there's a similar solution for OpenShift:

1. Install kubeadm with [snap](https://snapcraft.io/install/kubeadm/rhel):
   `sudo snap install kubeadm --classic`
2. `cd` to your openshift cluster installation directory.
3. Make a copy of your TLS certificate:
   `cp ./tls/journal-gatewayd.crt ./tls/ca.crt`
4. Make a copy of your TLS key:
   `cp ./tls/journal-gatewayd.key ./tls/ca.key`
5. Run kubeadm as follow:

   `kubeadm init phase kubeconfig admin --kubeconfig-dir ./auth --cert-dir "${PWD}/tls"`

   It should output: ***[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file***
6. `vi ./auth/admin.conf` - see that the certificates were added, and make sure the server address (`https://api.your-cluster:6443`) is correct.
7. Rename: `mv ./auth/admin.conf ./auth/kubeconfig` and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```sh
kubeadm init phase kubeconfig admin
```